# Fill an array with a sine to create a sine table

Tags: c++, math, audio

I'm Trying to fill an array with a sine to create a sine table to be used instead of the sin function to decrease the amount of the calculation.
Something is wrong with this C++ code, the array is always filled with the value 0.

```
#define TWO_PI (3.14159 * 2)
int16_t sineTable[32768];

const int32_t n = 32768;
const int16_t amp = 2047;
   
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {

        sineTable[i] = (sin(TWO_PI * (i / n)))*amp  ;
        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "test = %d",  sineTable[3567]);

    };
```

Comment: `i / n` is always zero. Both variables are integers so integer division is performed resulting in another integer. Use something like `((double)i / (double)n)` instead.

Comment: Or just remove the brackets so the multiplication by `TWO_PI` is done first `sin(TWO_PI * i / n)`. Association is left to right, so `TWO_PI * i` is first, that's a double times an integer, so the integer will automatically be converted to a double. Then the division happens which again will be a double divided by an integer, which again automatically converts the integer to a double.

Comment: Incidentally these two different methods will probably give slightly different answers because of rounding errors. Not completely certain but my feeling is that the first option should be preferred.

Comment: Final point, you certainly need a better approximation to pi. If you have C++20 available then you could `#include <numbers>` and use `std::numbers::pi` for the most accurate approximation. Otherwise just add a few more decimal places, you need 17 or so, `3.14159265358979323846264338`

Comment: Save three quarters of the calls to the sin() function by only calling it for angles up to Pi/2. The same values are then either used as-is or “minused” for the rest of the table.

Comment: Follow up question: In your original code you've defined the lookup table to be an array of `int16_t`, presumably because the target device uses (16 bit) integers. The accepted answer changes that to an array of `double`. Will you convert the `double`s to `int16_t` after lookup or did you change the target to use `double`s too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define sineTable as a double and define a better constant variable:

```
#define GRAD_TO_RAD (3.14159 * 2)/360

double sineTable[32768];
const int32_t n = 32768;
const int16_t amp = 2047;

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    sineTable[i] = amp * sin(i * GRAD_TO_RAD);
};
```

Note that john's comments might help also for a different solution or made a hybrid between our solutions.

### Edit

Using lastchance comment we can optimize the O(N) code AND THE MEMORY by using only pi/2 iterations.

My idea for this is using the derivative concept. Therefore we can approach this by using de differential. Basically, we can know when we are going off pi/2, knowing `sign[ΔѰ] != 1`, where ΔѰ will be differential between the last and new sin.

```
while (sin(i*GRAD_TO_RAD)>sin((i-1)*GRAD_TO_RAD))
{
    sineTable[i] = amp * sin(i * GRAD_TO_RAD);
    i++;
}
```

Note three imporant things here:

- sineTable is a dynamic array.
- This code it's just an example. Therefore, I think it will be way better codes to optimize what i just do. But I think it gets the idea.
- Be aware of accesing the value in this array. Hint: define four type entries depending in what quadrant the angle is.

  - quadrant 1: `sineTable[x]`
  - quadrant 2: `-sineTable[x]`
  - quadrant 3: `-sineTable[s]`
  - quadrant 4: `sineTable[s]`

Where "s" it's a representation of the symetric angle: `2 * sin_table_lenght - x`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` and `n` are both `int` and since `n` is always greater than `i`, the result of the division `(i / n)` will always be `0`.

You can make the calculation into using `double` simply by removing the parentheses:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sineTable[i] = std::sin(TWO_PI * i / n) * amp;
};
```

In `TWO_PI * i`, `i` will be converted to `double` and then in the division `n` will be converted to `double` too.

You may also want to do rounding to get the closest integer value:

```cpp
sineTable[i] = std::round(std::sin(TWO_PI * i / n) * amp);
```

Note: Prefer to use a proper constant instead of a macro for `TWO_PI`. Since C++20, `pi` is also included in the standard library, so use that:

```cpp
#include <numbers>
constexpr double TWO_PI = std::numbers::pi * 2;
```